# Separating Test Cases without repeating in Junit

Tags: java, function, junit, automated-tests

I've written a basic test for logging into Facebook. After that I want to write another test case that posts a status. I want to create a new function for that but how can I do that without repeating the whole log-in process.

```
        @Test
    public void Facebook_LoginTest() {

String title= null;
        // And now use this to visit facebook
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com ");


        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement id = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("pass"));
        WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton"));

         // Enter something to search for
        id.sendKeys("id@blah.com");
        password.sendKeys("blahblahblah");
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the login process to test initialization method (annotated with @Before) or to Fixture initialization method (annotated with @BeforeClass)